# Suggestions on introduction to model theory

Tags: logic, book-recommendation

Pretty much what the title says: does anyone have good suggestions for a nice introduction to model theory?

Answer (score 1):

You could start by reading sectiob 3.3. from van Dalen's textbook 'Logic and Structure'('Some Model Theory'). Afterwards try Manzano's 'Model Theory'. Finally have a look at serious model theory: Chang / Keisler: 'Model Theory', Hodges: 'Model Theory', Poizat: 'A Course in Model Theory'. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, I will check these out!